# Magento: Programmatically create associated products to a grouped one

Tags: magento

How can I Programmatically create/link associated products to a grouped one ??

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$products_links = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link_api');
$products_links->assign ("grouped",$group_product_id,$simple_product_id);
```

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link_Api.html

looks good in Magento 1.6.2.0